# What is compatible mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

From the [vimtutor](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vimtutor1.html)  *LESSON 7.3: COMPLETION*

> ```
>           ** Command line completion with CTRL-D and <TAB> **
> ```
>
> 1. Make sure Vim is not in compatible mode:  :set nocp
> 2. Look what files exist in the directory:  :!ls   or  :!dir
> 3. Type the start of a command:  :e
> 4. Press  CTRL-D  and Vim will show a list of commands that start with "e".

What does compatibility mode in Vim mean and why doesn't command completion work in that mode?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

*Compatible mode* means compatibility to venerable old [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi). When you `:set compatible`, all the enhancements and improvements of *Vi Improved* are turned off. It's not recommended to do this, but some systems provide (mostly for backwards compatibility with old Unix systems) a `vi` command that is implemented with Vim in compatible mode.

Note that once a personal initialization file `~/.vimrc` exists, Vim automatically turns on `'nocompatible'` mode, so this usually is nothing to worry about. For the full story, `:help 'compatible'` has all the details.

Comment: Does setting compatible also clear your vim history? I turned it on and somehow my history disappeared on me.