# VIM syntax highlighting works in MacVim but not vi in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, vim, colors

When I edit a file with `mvim` (Installed via MacVim) I see syntax highlighting in colour on a large range of files. However, when I edit with the built in `vi` there is *never* syntax highlighting. Is there something you need to do?

Colour does work with other terminal commands, e.g. `git`, `ls` etc... The problem is only with `vi`

Im on latest OS X 10.11.5:

```
> vi -version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Apr  5 2016 14:53:37)
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444340/how-to-specify-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-editor

Comment: That question and answer is about enabling syntax highlighting for certain file extensions.  That already works for me in `mvim` no work needed. My question is about why `vi` isn't operating the same way.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me - I changed the wording to "terminal" - if that's incorrect please roll it back.

Comment: What happens if you run `:syntax enable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vi` command is running `vim` in compatible mode. Try disabling it by adding this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set nocompatible
```

or running this command:

```
:set nocompatible
```

More info: [What is compatible mode in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/543317/what-is-compatible-mode-in-vim)